# problem in designing the listview in android application

Tags: android

I am developing an android application in which i have to integrate a listview in a resolution 320*480,The url is

http://www.crazysales.com.au/

can anyone help me regarding this

Thanks in advance
Tushar

Comment: http://www.google.co.in/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=custome+listview+example+android

Comment: you have to more specific , on which part of the design you are facing the problem or what exactly do u need?

Comment: @yashwanth kumar,,if u open the url that i have mentioned..list containing see all categories,,,'

Comment: you can make many text many image and some small thumb using Costume view with adapter.

Comment: @user813953 in this example http://appfulcrum.com/?p=311 , todoList.xml define all UI interface

Comment: @user813953 Are you basically looking on how to display the categories as a ListView in Android? If so, does the website provide API to retrieve that or are you planning to scrape the screen?

Comment: @nik,,,ok,,,,but this listview is very big,,,and i have to implement in 320*480 resolution,,,,,

Comment: make wrap_content and fill_parent in your xml layout so it is auto adjust.

Comment: @nik so the appfulcrum.com/?p=311  u have provided..i should use that ?

Comment: hmm,,,,,@nik,,,,,if u have done this type of layout,,can u send me a code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [**this**](http://appfulcrum.com/?p=311). using it you can make many text many image and some small thumb using Costume view with adapter. in this example , todoList.xml define all UI interface,and make wrap_content and fill_parent in your xml layout so it is auto adjust